# How to create a QR code an sone of one of the fields based on the other when creating an object?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create objects through admin panel in Django, I enter a value for a parameter and I want a qr code to be generated based on this value.

This is my code:

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    qr_code = models.ImageField(upload_to="img/qr_codes/", verbose_name="QR-code", null = True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=2, error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L, box_size=10, border=1)
        qr.add_data(self.name)
        qr.make(fit=True)
        qr.make_image().save(f'img/qr_codes/{self.name}.png')
        self.qr_code = self.name+'.png'
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This code return error

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'img/qr_codes/somename.png'

I'm trying to use signal `@receive` but it isn't helping me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your created the mentioned directories (`img/qr_codes/`). the method only creates file. It cannot create a directory.

Note: I think you missed a closing bracket `)` after your f-string. Is that the same in your code?

Comment: In my real code i dont forget this bracket) End my error exist with this bracket